# PowerBi- Prevent slicer from filtering a table returned measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I will do my best to explain this correctly. I have a data set that has 4 category columns (Date, Store, Provider, Pick Location) and 4 value columns (Total Orders, Total Deliveries, Accepted Deliveries, Assigned Deliveries). Please see the image here:
[image: Sample Data]

The two total columns should be grouped by date and store and have the same value regardless of the provider or pick location - There is the potential to see the same value up to 4 times depending on the category combination. The final two value columns will be different for every line and should not be grouped.

The issue I am facing is to be able to:

1. Sum up the total columns by the date/store group to ensure there is no duplication
2. Sum up the other value columns NOT by the date/store group without affecting the totals
3. Have the total columns be only affected by the Date and Store slicer (NOT the Provider and Location)
4. Have the other values filter as normal for all slicers
5. Ultimately calculate percentages of "total" based on the affected slicers.

Here is a visual summary of what I would be trying to accomplish:

[image: final summary]

Currently, I have been able to create a "sum of averages" to allow the total values to display correctly based on the date and store, but am unable to get it to ignore the provider and location slicer:

```
total_pro_orders_f = var _table=SUMMARIZE(md_pbi_datafile,md_pbi_datafile[date], md_pbi_datafile[store_number],"_orders", averagex(md_pbi_datafile, md_pbi_datafile[total_pro_orders]))
RETURN
calculate(SUMX(_table,[_orders]), REMOVEFILTERS(md_pbi_datafile[lpName],md_pbi_datafile[transaction_is_sourced]))
```

I have tried all the different ignore filter commands I could find but no matter what I do I cannot get the totals to stay the same regardless of provider or location.

Does anyone have any advice on how to accomplish this?

Thank you all!

Comment: Is your second table of expected results supposed to correlate with the first table you give? The numbers don't seem right. Also, remember that pictures are not of much use to those wanting to help but needing to test potential solutions on realistic datasets: copiable data is much more appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the response Jos-  I will look to see how to get the dataset posted/uploaded correctly.  In regard to your question:  The two columns in Yellow are "Total" columns and would be the same for every date store combo. In the dataset it is dupe'd but, only one of group should be counted when rolled up (marked in orange). Therefore in the second table, regardless of the filters mentioned, those two values should remain the same and any calculation would be done against those totals. Currently I have accomplished this by "summing the average" of the group but am open to other options.